# Am getting an unexpected in opencv 3.4.3

Tags: c++, opencv

The following the the code to load the image tree

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    Mat testobject = imread("tree",IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    if (testobject.empty())
        std::cout << "failed to open img.jpg" 
<<std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "img.jpg loaded OK" << std::endl;


    imshow("color", testobject);
    waitKey();
    return(0);

}
```

but am getting the following output

```
failed to open img.jpg
```

and error as

```
OpenCV(3.4.3) Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, file C:\build\3_4_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 356
```

Am using visual studio 2017

can anybody please help me out this my first open cv program

Comment: I am pretty sure that file name is "tree.jpg" :)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to open/read a file named "tree" (not img.jpg, not tree.jpg, etc). Is there a file named just "tree" within the project directory?

Comment: am sorry the file name is tree.jpg which is same folder as my visua studio project irrespective of my cout output img.jpg

Comment: But does the name of the file match the name given to `imread` ?

Comment: yes it does, but even then i am encountering error

Answer (score 0):

In code you should have

```
Mat testobject = imread("tree.jpg",IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
```

Image should be in file where You have cpp files, not where sln file is.